# How to zip a folder recursively with Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, zip

I would like to zip a folder recursevely with clojure. An example of such a folder would be

```
├── a
├── b
│   ├── c
│   │   └── ccc.txt
│   └── bb.txt
├── c
├── a.txt
└── b.txt
```

**Option 1 : using the OS from within Clojure**

What works with `zip` in Ubuntu is to execute following in the root of this structure :

```
zip -r result.zip *
```

But you have to be in the working dir in order to do this.  Using absolute paths will yield other results and omiting paths all together will flatten the structure of course.

Problem is that you cannot change the working directory in Clojure, not that I'm aware of that is..

**Option 2 : using native Clojure (or Java)**

This should be possible, and I find some zip implementations in Clojure or Java wrappers.  Most of them however for single files.

This might be a solution : http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/java-io/973-how-work-zip-files-java.html

but before I try that out I'd like to now or there isn't a good Clojure library around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about something like this using [clojure.core/file-seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/file-seq)

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(import '[java.util.zip ZipEntry ZipOutputStream])

(with-open [zip (ZipOutputStream. (io/output-stream "foo.zip"))]
  (doseq [f (file-seq (io/file "/path/to/directory")) :when (.isFile f)]
    (.putNextEntry zip (ZipEntry. (.getPath f)))
    (io/copy f zip)
    (.closeEntry zip)))
```

Comment: very nice!  I check it out a bit more when I have the time, but will certainly accept if it works out.

Comment: Neat, but not recursive yet :)

Comment: @JamesSharp `file-seq` uses `tree-seq` which is a depth-first walk.

Comment: @kyle if I understand it correctly `:when (.isFile f)` will discard subdirectories. We'd need something like `(defn zip-folder
""
[path filename zstream]  
(with-open [zip (or zstream (ZipOutputStream. (io/output-stream filename)))]
  (doseq [f (file-seq (io/file path))]
    (if (.isFile f)
      (do
        (.putNextEntry zip (ZipEntry. (.getPath f)))
        (io/copy f zip)
        (.closeEntry zip))
      (if (.isDirectory f)
          (zip-folder (.getPath f) filename zip))))))` Untested though

Comment: no, subdirs are not discarded (I have just tested it), I have however another problem :  path/to/dir is always zipped, even if my structure is only beginning in 'dir' , empty path/to dirs are also zipped...

Comment: @Peter are empty directories discarded using the command line?

Comment: @Peter the path can be relative to the current working directory - not sure if that helps you.

Comment: @Kyle : this works fine for almost any usecase, however there's a tricky problem I have : only files are added, not dirs. The files however have all the path info they need, en when unzipping the directory structure is recovered fine.    But as long as you are not extracting, *internaly* there are no dirs.  I need the unzipped file to be exactly the right format, so the question here : how to also add directory entries?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks](https://github.com/rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks) library that wraps [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/), and zip/unzip in a single line of code.

Add library dependency [rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks "1.0.1"]

```
(require '[rtcritical.clj-ant-tasks :refer [run-ant-task])
```

To zip a directory:

```
(run-ant-task :zip {:destfile "/tmp/archive.zip" :basedir "/tmp/archive"})
```

Zip a directory, where the base directory is included in the archive:

```
(run-ant-task :zip {:destfile "/tmp/archive.zip" 
                    :basedir "/tmp" 
                    :includes "archive/**"})
```

Note: run-ant-task(s) functions in this library namespace can be used to run any other Apache Ant task(s) as well.

For more information, see https://github.com/rtcritical/clj-ant-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/AeroNotix/swindon *A nice little wrapper around java.util.zip. using streams* and https://github.com/chmllr/zeus a *Simple Clojure library for zip-based compression*

Comment: I have, neither is a solution

Comment: Have you checked Raynes tests for compression? https://github.com/Raynes/fs/blob/master/test/me/raynes/core_test.clj#L335 it could be a good start to traverse the directory tree and zip it. It also has different compression algorithms and decent docs http://raynes.github.io/fs/me.raynes.fs.compression.html

Comment: I know of his fine library and use it, but not for compression yet, I didn't find solutions for directories if I recall well, thanks for the tip however.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Kyle answer:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(import '[java.util.zip ZipEntry ZipOutputStream])


(defn zip-folder
  "p input path, z output zip"
  [p z]
  (with-open [zip (ZipOutputStream. (io/output-stream z))]
    (doseq [f (file-seq (io/file p)) :when (.isFile f)]
      (.putNextEntry zip (ZipEntry. (str/replace-first (.getPath f) p "") ))
      (io/copy f zip)
      (.closeEntry zip)))
  (io/file z))
```